# Pandas Compare Multiple Columns and Return Longest String to New Col

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with multiple columns that I'm trying to merge into a single column, keeping the longer string. Unfortunately I'm getting lost with how to do this. There are a limited number of potential columns, there may two or more (two is the most likely scenario).

```
potential_columns = ["name", "full_name", "complete_name", ...]
actual_columns = set(dataframe.columns).intersect(potential_columns)

df[actual_columns]
       full_name                      name
0      Philip J Fry                   Fry
1      Bender                         Bender Bending Rodriguez 
2      Turanga Leela                  Leela
```

Basically I want to perform something like `df["new_col"] = max("Philip J Fry", "Fry")` and place the result into a new column. And that's where I'm getting stuck.

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? Have you tried breaking down the problem on paper, writing some pseudocode, etc. ? Please see [mcve], [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try `max` with `key`

```
df['New']=df.apply(lambda x : max(x,key=len),axis=1)
df
       full_name                       name                        New
0   Philip J Fry                        Fry               Philip J Fry
1         Bender  Bender Bending Rodriguez   Bender Bending Rodriguez 
2  Turanga Leela                      Leela              Turanga Leela
```

Or with `np.where`

```
df['New']=np.where(df.full_name.str.len()>df.name.str.len(),df.full_name,df.name)
df
       full_name                       name                        New
0   Philip J Fry                        Fry               Philip J Fry
1         Bender  Bender Bending Rodriguez   Bender Bending Rodriguez 
2  Turanga Leela                      Leela              Turanga Leela
```

Comment: Thanks! I was getting an error but it seemed to have resolved itself after I mapped them to strings!

`test["new_column"] = test[actual_columns].apply(lambda x: max(x, key=len), axis=1)`

Comment: @TWDickson good finding , if this help , would you like accept it ? check mark at the left ~

Comment: Np. Sorry it didn't let me accept that it right away. The first option is definitely better because the column names can shift from dataset to dataset and it could potentially be N columns to compare.

Answer (score 1):

```
df["newcol"] = df.apply(lambda x: x['full_name'] if len(x['full_name'] > len(x['name']) else x['name'], axis = 1)
```

Should work.